# Android DatePicker day of month off by one?

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, timepicker

I'm trying to create a unix timestamp using the datepicker and timepicker dialogs but the problem occurring is that the day is always off by one. E.g. if I pick May 10 it will display May 11 as the output. Everything else however seems to work no problem. Any suggestions would be great.

The date and timepicker code looks as follows...

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
        }
    };

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mHour = hourOfDay;
        mMinute = minute;
        confirmDateChange();
    }
};

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
    return new TimePickerDialog(this,
            mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);          
    }
    return null;
}
```

Next I call this to get a timestamp

```
 private long componentTimeToTimestamp(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);       
    return (c.getTimeInMillis()/1000L);        
}
```

And lastly this sets the value at a textview but like I said the day of the month is always off by one

```
    long mydate = componentTimeToTimestamp(mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute);   
    long datemod = mydate * 1000;
    final java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(datemod);       
    details.setText(d.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: toLocaleString() is deprecated I think. Off the top of my head I forget what exactly is the current preferred way. I think it is the DateFormat class. You might try using that to turn your long into a dateStr and see if it makes a difference. If it is consistently off by one always it would be quicker and easier but certainly not "correct" to just roll the day back one before you display it.

Comment: The method words fine because I use it to add timestamps to the database and retrieve them. This works perfectly: long timestamp = date * 1000;
            java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(timestamp); 
            mDate.setText(d.toLocaleString());

Comment: If you are 100% sure that method works then the error could be due to the divide by 1000L then multiply by 1000, I don't see why that would be a problem though. Or else the date picker is reporting wrong. Perhaps dump the info the DatePicker is giving you to the Log before you send it through the ToTimeStamp() method see if it is coming out correct there.

Comment: I figured it out. I used this         c.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
and it worked :)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it. You might put that as an answer and accept it so that it will be easier for people who come across this in the future to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Though You figured out the answer in comment.But u must have answered it here as most of the people wont confuse that it has not not been answered.Please read the comments and then go for this answer

```
 c.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
```